# apply z-score for all 2D slice( dependently only by data in each single 2d image) in a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have  a numpy 3D array `input_array`,with a dimension of 480x480x661,which contains 661 images each with a dimension of 480x480. I would like to create another numpy array `out`,where in all images I've applied z-score ( dependently only by data in each single 2d image). I'm using `scipy.stats.zscore`.    This code works,but I've no idea if is doing exactly what i want,can you check?

```py
for ii in range(np.size(input_array,2)):
    out=scipy.stats.zscore(input_array[:,:,ii],axis=None)
```

Comment: You can specify the `axis` parameter to be `(0,1)` in `scipy.stats.zscore` function

Comment: @FBruzzesi ok thanks,is different from None,if i have just selected a 2D slice with [[:,:,ii]?